# Is every axiomatizable theory $T$ countable?

Tags: logic, decidability

These are the definitions I'll be working with. (Note that they are informal and the author promises more formal ones later on in the book, but I'm not there yet.)

> A set $Z$ of strings of a given alphabet $\mathsf{A}$ is called *decidable* if there is an algorithm (a mechanical decision procedure) that after finitely many calculation steps provides us with an answer to the question whether a string $\xi$ of symbols of $\mathsf{A}$ belongs to $Z$. [...] A theory $T$ is called *recursively axiomatizable*, or just *axiomatizable*, if it possesses a decidable axiom system.

At first glance, it seems to me that an uncountable theory $T$ could be decidable, as it seems possible that an algorithm could determine whether a string belongs to its axiom system $X$, for all strings of an alphabet. However, here my doubts come up. The author provides a sketch of the following theorem.

> *The theorems of an axiomatizable theory are effectively enumerable.*

He defines enumerability in this way.

> Put roughly, a set $M$ [...] is called *effectively* (or *recursively*) *enumerable* if there exists an algorithm that delivers the elements of $M$ stepwise.

However, if an axiom system $X$ of some theory $T$ is uncountable, so is $T$ itself, and there can be no algorithm that could deliver the elements of $T$ (and therefore of the set containing all of the theorems of $T$, since $T$ is a subset of this set) stepwise. (This is because there is no bijection $f\colon \, \mathbb{N} \to T$, as $T$ is uncountable.) The conclusion seems to be that $T$ being axiomatizable implies it being countable.

My question concerns my understanding of the definition of decidability. I interpreted the author's definition as saying that the algorithm deciding the membership of each string $\xi$ runs on all strings *simultaneously*. If the author meant to say that the algorithm can only process one string per step, then it, of course, trivially follows that no uncountable set is decidable. I am grateful for all clarifications of this confusion. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, but what exactly is an uncountable theory? Isn't the collection of all possible statements (in first order logic) countable anyway? I mean alphabet is a finite set and string is a finite sequence of elements of alphabet, ergo there are countably many strings. Also an algorithm, meaning Turing machine, cannot be applied to uncountable sets. The concept heavily depends on finite sets of symbols, states and transistions. I don't think that can work for uncountable universe.

Comment: @freakish An uncountable theory is indeed possible if we have a language with uncountably many non-logical symbols (i.e., predicate symbols and function symbols). Then the language itself (i.e., the set of all formulas of this language) is uncountable and we can just set some uncountable subset $X$ (it's not hard to find) of this language as the axiom system for our theory $T$, and voilà, we have an uncountable theory.

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't look like a useful concept to me. Can you give an example of a language with uncountably many symbols? I mean, concrete, not just theoretical. Does the author consider such things? Can you give a reference to the book/paper?

Comment: @freakish Yes, the author considers the possibility of uncountable languages. The book I'm reading is *A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (Third Edition) by Wolfgang Rautenberg. He mentions uncountable languages on p. 118 (and probably elsewhere, but I forgot about it).

Comment: @freakish The elementary diagram of the real field is the complete theory of the real numbers considered as a field with a constant symbol naming every real number - so the language has size continuum. A model of this theory is a field $K$ into which $\mathbb{R}$ embeds (elementarily). These kinds of theories are used all the time in model theory.

Comment: BUT it really doesn't make any sense to ask computability-theoretic questions like decidability or recursive axiomatizability when the language is uncountable. As @freakish says, the input to a Turing machines comes in the form of a finite alphabet, so there's just no way to code an uncountable language into a form that a Turing machine can process.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Wouldn't a countable alphabet work too, though? If a language has a countable signature, it's countable.

Comment: Yes, of course. My point is that Turing machines deal with strings from a finite alphabet. If a first-order signature is countable, then formulas over that signature can be coded as strings over a finite alphabet, and therefore it makes sense to ask computability-theoretic questions about them.